# PostgreSQL unnest with empty array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I use postgreSQL 9.1. In my database there is a table which looks like

```
id | ... | values
-----------------------
1  | ... | {1,2,3}
2  | ... | {}
```

where id is an integer and values is an integer array. The arrays can be empty.

I need to unnest this list. If I query

```
select id, ..., unnest(values)
from table
```

I get three rows for id = 1 (as expected) and no lines for id = 2. Is there a way to get a result like

```
id  | ... | unnest
-------------------
1   | ... | 1
1   | ... | 2
1   | ... | 3
2   | ... | null
```

i.e. a query which also contains the lines which have an empty array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select id, 
       case 
         when int_values is null or array_length(int_values,1) is null then null
         else unnest(int_values)
       end as value
from the_table;
```

(note that I renamed the column `values` to `int_values` as `values` is a reserved word and should not be used as a column name).

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a0bb4/1

---

Postgres 10 does not allow to use `unnest()` like that any more.

You need to use a lateral join:

```
select id, t.i
from the_table
   cross join lateral unnest(coalesce(nullif(int_values,'{}'),array[null::int])) as t(i);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ALNX23313

---

It can be simplified even further when using a left join instead of the cross join:

```
select id, t.i
from the_table
 left join lateral unnest(int_values) as t(i) on true;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/VBO52351

Answer (score 17):

This works on Postgres 10 also:

```
SELECT id, UNNEST(CASE WHEN "values" <> '{}' THEN "values" ELSE '{null}' END)
```

Comment: I ended up going with the lateral join, but I really appreciate this solution as sometimes I just want to inline my unnests and not join them ... Additionally a cursory explain suggested that this approach may be  tad more efficient than the lateral join ... Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 4):

#### Original answer

This works up to **Postgres 9.6**. The behavior of set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list was changed (sanitized) in Postgres 10. See below!

Upon revisiting this question it struck me that this can be **simpler** and faster.
Reverse the logic of the [currently accepted solution by @a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15175556/939860):

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN values <> '{}' THEN unnest(values) END AS value
FROM   tbl;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uZLylfRr)

This returns a row with `NULL` in `value` for an **empty array** as well as for a **`NULL`** array, because only an array with elements in it produces `TRUE` in the test `values <> '{}'`.

Works for arrays of *any* type, since the literal '{}' is automatically coerced to a matching type.

Without explicit `ELSE` branch, `CASE` returns `NULL`, which is what we want anyway.

Arrays with a `NULL` elements will return rows regardless.

**However.** I found an anomaly and posted a question concerning that:

- [NULL emements lost when casting result of unnest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452501/null-emements-lost-when-casting-result-of-unnest)

Turned out to be a bug that was fixed after my report for pg 9.3+.

#### Since Postgres 10

The short syntax above stops working after the behavior of set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list has been reworked (sanitized). See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

A `LATERAL` subquery is the clean, versatile solution, and works since Postgres 9.3, where `LATERAL` was added:

```sql
SELECT t.id, v.value
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.values) AS v(value) ON true;
```

Or, with minimal syntax:

```sql
SELECT id, value
FROM   tbl
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(values) value ON true;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YE2CtQQh)

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Trying this solution in postgres 12, I get: 
set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
LINE 5:   case when values <> '{}' then unnest(values...
                                                      ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item

Comment: @W1M0R: The behavior of SRFs was sanitized in Postgres 10. As a side-effect, my old short syntax stops working. I updated to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
    unnest (
        "values"
        ||
        (array[null]::integer[])[1:(array_upper("values", 1) is null)::integer]
    )
from "table"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use self `LEFT JOIN`, like this (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/95bad/1)):

```sql
SELECT t.id, u.u
  FROM tab t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, unnest(vals) u FROM tab) u
    USING (id);
```

Note, that for bigger tables query will be performing badly.