# Postgres 10 lateral unnest missing null values

Tags: postgresql, null, lateral

I have a Postgres table where the content of a text column is delimited with '|'.

```
ID | ... | my_column
-----------------------
1  | ... | text|concatenated|as|such
2  | ... | NULL
3  | ... | NULL
```

I tried to unnest(string_to_array()) this column to separate rows which works fine, except that my NULL values (>90% of all entries) are excluded. I have tried several approaches:

```
 SELECT * from "my_table", lateral unnest(CASE WHEN "this_column" is NULL
 THEN NULL else string_to_array("this_column", '|') END);
```

or

as suggested here: [PostgreSQL unnest with empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175187/postgresql-unnest-with-empty-array)

What I get:

```
ID | ... | my_column
-----------------------
1  | ... | text
1  | ... | concatenated
1  | ... | as
1  | ... | such
```

But this is what I need:

```
ID | ... | my_column
-----------------------
1  | ... | text
1  | ... | concatenated
1  | ... | as
1  | ... | such
2  | ... | NULL
3  | ... | NULL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT m.id, t.*
from my_table m
   left join lateral unnest(string_to_array(my_column, '|')) as t(w) on true;
```

There is no need for the CASE statement to handle NULL values. `string_to_array` will handle them correctly.

Online example: http://rextester.com/XIGXP80374

Comment: Great! What a quick answer. Thank you